# How to parse an XML file where there are two different transactions with all same sub tags but one tag is different using DOM parser in JAVA?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I have an XML document as follows:

```
<Transactions>
<Transaction>
  <TransactionType>Account Payable</TransactionType>
  <TransactionFor>Supplier</TransactionFor>
  <TransactionDate>09/11/2015 00:40:31</TransactionDate>
  <ItemReference>Hotels</ItemReference>
  <Amount>3420.00</Amount>
  <AmountPaid>0.00</AmountPaid>
  <Balance>3420.00</Balance>
  <Status>Open</Status>
  <SupplierID>3930d9cd-1d8a-4e4d-99d3-4cd4b208795d</SupplierID>
</Transaction>
<Transaction>
  <TransactionType>Account Receivable</TransactionType>
  <TransactionFor>Consumer</TransactionFor>
  <TransactionDate>09/11/2015 00:40:31</TransactionDate>
  <ItemReference>Hotels</ItemReference>
  <Amount>3420.00</Amount>
  <AmountPaid>3420.00</AmountPaid>
  <Balance>0.00</Balance>
  <Status>Closed</Status>
  <ConsumerID>65e3dbb6-4353-4fbb-8e8b-28d0c09dc728</ConsumerID>
</Transaction>
</Transactions>
```

How can I parse this in Java when one tag is different like for example, `supplierId` and `consumerId`?

I have implemented the code for this, but getting a `NullPointerException`:

```
NodeList nList8 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Transaction");

for (int temp8 = 0; temp8 < nList8.getLength(); temp8++) 
{
    Node nNode8 = nList8.item(temp8);
    if (nNode8.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
    {
        Element eElement8 = (Element) nNode8;                       
        System.out.println("TransactionType : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("TransactionType").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("TransactionFor : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("TransactionFor").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("TransactionDate : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("TransactionDate").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("ItemReference : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("ItemReference").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Amount : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("Amount").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("AmountPaid : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("AmountPaid").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Balance : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("Balance").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Status : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("Status").item(0).getTextContent());
        if(eElement8.getElementsByTagName("SupplierID").item(0).getTextContent()==null)
        {
            System.out.println("ConsumerID : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("ConsumerID").item(0).getTextContent());    
        }
        else if(eElement8.getElementsByTagName("ConsumerID").item(0).getTextContent() == null)
            System.out.println("SupplierID : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("SupplierID").item(0).getTextContent());
    }
}
```

Comment: @SyedAqib you are getting null pointer exception in                          NodeList nList8 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Transaction"); this line measn doc is null.. try to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you are attempting to access the child node(s) via `.item(0).getTextContent()` before you have tested whether the parent element (`SupplierID` or `ConsumerID`) exists:

```
            if (eElement8.getElementsByTagName("SupplierID").item(0).getTextContent() == null)
            {

            } else if (eElement8.getElementsByTagName("ConsumerID").item(0).getTextContent() == null) {

            }
```

The approach you are taking is sound, but you will need to perform null checks at each level while you are walking the tree. Ultimately, you should start at the top-level element you are working with, and work your way down one element at a time.

If you want to skip null checks, you will be best served by first validating your document against a schema or DTD, if one exists, to ensure that the document conforms to the expected structure before you attempt to access nodes. However, the above code is still problematic.

I recommend separating out your parsing from your business logic in the following way (original method is `parse1()`, new method is `parse2()`):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class DomTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        File iFile = new File("src/main/resources/domtest.xml");

        try
        {
            Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream(iFile));

            new DomTest().parse2(doc);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            System.out.println("Failed to parse " + iFile.getAbsolutePath());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void parse1(Document doc)
    {
        NodeList nList8 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Transaction");

        for (int temp8 = 0; temp8 < nList8.getLength(); temp8++) 
        {
            Node nNode8 = nList8.item(temp8);

            if (nNode8.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
            {
                Element eElement8 = (Element) nNode8;   

                System.out.println("TransactionType : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("TransactionType").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("TransactionFor : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("TransactionFor").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("TransactionDate : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("TransactionDate").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("ItemReference : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("ItemReference").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Amount : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("Amount").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("AmountPaid : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("AmountPaid").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Balance : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("Balance").item(0).getTextContent());
                System.out.println("Status : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("Status").item(0).getTextContent());

                if (eElement8.getElementsByTagName("SupplierID").item(0).getTextContent() == null)
                {
                    System.out.println("ConsumerID : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("ConsumerID").item(0).getTextContent());                                    
                } else if (eElement8.getElementsByTagName("ConsumerID").item(0).getTextContent() == null) {
                    System.out.println("SupplierID : " + eElement8.getElementsByTagName("SupplierID").item(0).getTextContent());
                }
            }
        }

        return;
    }

    public void parse2(Document doc)
    {
        Element transactionsEl = doc.getDocumentElement();

        NodeList transactionEls = transactionsEl.getElementsByTagName("Transaction");

        for (int txIdx = 0; txIdx < transactionEls.getLength(); txIdx++) 
        {
            // we know that this an Element node because we used getElementsByTagName above
            Element transactionEl = (Element) transactionEls.item(txIdx);

            String transactionType = null;
            String transactionFor = null;
            String transactionDate = null;
            String itemReference = null;
            String amount = null;
            String amountPaid = null;
            String balance = null;
            String status = null;
            String consumerID = null;
            String supplierID = null;

            NodeList transactionElChildNodes = transactionEl.getChildNodes();

            for (int i = 0; i < transactionElChildNodes.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node n = transactionElChildNodes.item(i);

                if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                {
                    Element someEl = (Element) n;

                    String elName = someEl.getTagName();
                    String text = someEl.getTextContent();

                    if (elName.equals("TransactionType"))
                    {
                        transactionType = text;
                    } else if (elName.equals("TransactionFor")) {
                        transactionFor = text;
                    } else if (elName.equals("TransactionDate")) {
                        transactionDate = text;
                    } else if (elName.equals("ItemReference")) {
                        itemReference = text;
                    } else if (elName.equals("Amount")) {
                        amount = text;
                    } else if (elName.equals("AmountPaid")) {
                        amountPaid = text;
                    } else if (elName.equals("Balance")) {
                        balance = text;
                    } else if (elName.equals("Status")) {
                        status = text;
                    } else if (elName.equals("SupplierID")) {
                        supplierID = text;
                    } else if (elName.equals("ConsumerID")) {
                        consumerID = text;
                    }
                }
            }

            // business logic follows:

            System.out.println("Transaction " + String.valueOf(txIdx));

            if (supplierID != null)
            {
                System.out.println("SupplierID: " + supplierID);
            }

            if (consumerID != null)
            {
                System.out.println("ConsumerID: " + consumerID);
            }
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Transaction 0
SupplierID: 3930d9cd-1d8a-4e4d-99d3-4cd4b208795d 
Transaction 1
ConsumerID: 65e3dbb6-4353-4fbb-8e8b-28d0c09dc728
```

Comment: Thank you vallis for the solution :)

Answer (score -1):

XML means **eXtensible** Markup Language

**1 You can put any structure, any tree and any node in one xml file**, if only they respect simple rules: open tag must have a symetric end tag, somes constraints on characters.

It is really very open, you can put Mo (Go ?), and it is robust, due to open/close tags.

And you can further add new datas, without breaking your apps (next point).

**2 then you could parse them**

search on SO for some parsers and examples. And look at xpath too.

You parse and you get what you want. If there are too many datas, you get forget them (or not if you want strict format ...).

**3 note that a tag is not unique**: you can repeat him (and even use it at sub-level, even sub-taging with the same tag).

**4 then problem is perhaps in your design**, and what you want to do when you parse.

If one element has one tag (*supplierId*) and another not, what do you want to do ? create different objects, process differently ? It is up to you.

**5 if you want strict rules about which data and structure you accept**, you can use also DTD/XML schema and tools and libraries to check xml input.

Hope it helps.